# What is the point of constructor chaining in java and how to combine it with tostring()?

Tags: java, constructor, constructor-chaining

So i know how to use it, how it works.The question what is the point in real life scenario.
Imagine created class without `toString()` overriding. So what is the point in that class if you can't display it properly ??

And please try not to explain how constructor chaining works or something like that.
I know how it works. I want to know does anyone do this in real life 
because without `toString()` overriding i don't see the point

```
   public class ConstructorChaining {

        String a;
        int b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;

        public ConstructorChaining() {
            this("");
        }


        public ConstructorChaining(String a) {
            this(a, 0);

        }

        public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b) {
            this(a, b, 0);

        }

        public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, int c) {
            this(a, b, c, 0);

        }

        public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, int c, int d) {
            this(a, b, c, d, 0);

        }

        public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
            this.e = e;
        }

    }
```

so imagine i created an object

```
ConstructorChaining constructorChaining=new ConstructorChaining("name");
```

and tried to print it

```
System.out.println(constructorChaining);
```

How do i implement `toString()` for this

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're referring to?  I can't think of any meaning for the term "constructor chaining" that bears any meaningful relationship to `toString()`.

Comment: ok , so you created a class and that class have constructor chaining,but does not implement toString method and you want to print object and you get somethin like Object[ 235gDfiiag  . And now you try to implement toString() the question is how ?every constructor calls another

Comment: @DanielBaker please [edit] to show some code, rather than trying to describe it.

Comment: Constructor chaining and `toString()` are not related.  If you want to print the object and get a meaningful result, override `toString`; that has nothing to do with constructors.

Comment: "How do i implement toString() for this" `@Override public String toString() { ... }`. It's no different to without all these constructors.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that is exactly what i'm asking > HOW ?

Comment: If you're using an IDE, get it to generate your `toString()` method. Inspect the code it generates, inspect the output it generates when you run it, and change it to match your requirements.

Comment: @user added code

Comment: I almost never override toString.

Comment: ggr is right. Most objects don't have to be displayed, they just do their thing

Comment: @user but it's not an unreasonable question to ask how you /would/ implement it, if this is one of the objects that does have to be displayed.

Comment: @AndyTurner true, but the OP said that they didn't see the point in real life if you couldn't override it

Comment: @AndyTurner yeap exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this, using a field that is set differently based on the constructor you called:

```
public class ConstructorChaining {

   String a;
   int b;
  //This value is different for each constructor, so you can control your
  //toString implementation
  String asString;

public ConstructorChaining() {
            this("");
        }


        public ConstructorChaining(String a) {
            this(a, 0, a + "");

        }

        public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b) {
            this(a, b, 0, a + "" + b);

        }

        private ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, String asString) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.asString = asString;
        }

@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Overriden toString, asString = " + asString;
}
```

Comment: and what if i give only two parameters? and don't want the others to be printed ?

Comment: Guys i know how print in method or static method or something, I wanna know what is the point of constructor chaining if you can't display object

Comment: nice ))) but i will make the last one private it doesn't make sense other way  and you have a typo         this(a, b, 0, a + "" + b); delete 0

Comment: public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, String asString)  not private

Comment: Constructing a fixed string initially and storing it in the object is a bad idea for multiple reasons. For one, it's redundant information. For another, now every new constructor you add has to rethink what they want the string to look like. Then when any of the field values that went into the string change, you need to recompute the string on every such change.

Comment: @user Thanks a lot

Comment: @G.Bach That's true, but it's apparently what the OP wanted, to control the toString method using the constructor. Might be the XY problem

Comment: @G.Bach a lot of theory which all over books and every tutorial , and i read those ,but non of them telling what is the point of chaining if you can't display the object properly , just was curious how to do it , AND know i'm sure that this a pointless concept and don't do anything good

Comment: @DanielBaker I meant constructor chaining isn't what you seem to think - a way to override methods. And yes, it is used a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class ConstructorChaining {

    String a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;

    public ConstructorChaining() {
        this("");
    }


    public ConstructorChaining(String a) {
        this(a, 0);

    }

    public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b) {
        this(a, b, 0);

    }

    public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, int c) {
        this(a, b, c, 0);

    }

    public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, int c, int d) {
        this(a, b, c, d, 0);

    }

    public ConstructorChaining(String a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return "ConstructorChaining={a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c + ", d=" + d + ", e=" + e;
    }
}
```

Look what your friends are telling you, there is no relation between the contractors and the toString overridden method.

All the primitive types are already initialized as 0 so you don't need to care if the values are there or not.

Comment: I don't want to print values i didn't set in constructor ?